# Can't Unregister a ContentObserver

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

So, This is the Code im using in a Service :

1. The Service Start & Run this Code :

   ```
     SmsObserver smsSentObserver = new SmsObserver(new Handler(), this);
     this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true,            
     smsSentObserver);
   ```

Then the Service stopSelf()

2.The Service Start & Run this Code :

```
      SmsObserver smsSentObserver = new SmsObserver(new Handler(), this);
      this.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(smsSentObserver);
```

Then the Service stopSelf(),

Problem : the ContentObserver is Not unregistred & keep to receive the onChange Method

Additionnal info : Everything worked fine before, it is related to KitKat or what is wrong Here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you are c reating a different object for your `Observer` so maybe is that the reason it is giving you trouble.

Keep a reference of your  `SmsObserver` in your service, and use that variable to call to `unregisterContentObserver`.

That should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, i was thinking this Too but the Problem is that i can't keep the Service Running because those Methods can be Called at any times, is there another Way ?

Comment: Okay inspired from your Answer i have Found a Solution : ill make a Persistent Service & put the unregister Code into the onDestroy() Methods, So every times the Service is Stopped then the ContentObserver is Unregistred But the Service is with the Flag Start_Sticky to make it Persistent

Comment: Even using this Method, the ContentObserver is still Not unregistred, i dont get it Why, i was thinking about a Rom Specific Problem but im Not Sure because someone else has Tested & the Same Bug Happen - Using the Rom Google Play Edition Android 4.4.4 for Galaxy S4

Comment: I had something similar in my SGS4 default rom with 4.4.2 and it is working fine :S

Comment: its weird... i hope im the Only One to have this Problem, Or i hope this is Not Related to Android 4.4.4...